# How to tell a supervisor that I got a PhD position without his recommendation letter?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter

I was applying for a Ph.D. position and my supervisor wanted me to apply to a few of his collaborator's labs which subjects or work never attracted me. Also, he always wanted all his students to apply to a specific country. He was like he will only write LOR if his students apply to that country.
So when I applied I did not recommend his name and took LOR from other professors (who are big shots) and I secured a Ph.D. position.
Now how can I tell him that I got a Ph.D. position where I did not use his name as a recommender? Is there any polite way so that he doesn't feel bad?

Comment: It seems you want to do something impolite, for impolite reasons. At least, that how your post comes accross: "Look, I didn't need your letter!"

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about his feelings too much. If he is a decent person he will want to congratulate you on your success. If he isn't then how he "feels" is the least of your problems. But "I was lucky enough to obtain a position at xyz" is the message to send. Not "I was lucky enough to obtain a position at xyz without your help". And thanking him for support in earning your degree is always a positive message.

It should be a minor matter, though he may reply that he wished you'd applied in the "preferred" country.